# What is "!!" filter used for?

Tags: filter

can anyone give me an example of how `!!` works? The documentation says:

```
!!{filter}      Filter [count] lines through the external program {filter}.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`!!` (and more generally the `!` operator) provides vim builtin support for all the unix filters that have evolved over the ages: this includes `cut`, `paste`, `sort`, `uniq`, `awk`, `sed`, even `bash`. Basically a filter is anything that can transform stdin to stdout (possibly doing something meaningful—the identity filter is just `cat`).

By providing access to these tools, vim avoids re-inventing them and allows you to combine them however you see fit. Table editing, cleaning a csv file, even interpreting lines of a shell script on the fly... the possibilities are about as limitless as the construction of *nix pipelines.

---

For a concrete example, type

```
echo Hello World
```

In a new file, then `!!sh -` and hit enter (I think I have that syntax right).

Also see [this answer of mine](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/18997/10604) for more complex techniques.

Comment: That's a good answer. what's difference between "!" and "!!"?

Comment: `!!` is like `!` for a single line. `!` can work on arbitrary ranges, so for example `!3j`, `!ap` or `V/}<CR>!`

Comment: @user12457 also see `:help !`

Answer (score 3):

A classic example for this filter is to sort the input using the Shell command `sort`. So vi does not have to implement its own sorting algorithm but could plugin external commands to do that.

Nowadays, Vim comes with its own sort implementation as `:sort` command, mainly because some systems did not provide a sort binary.